# How to make the first line of a WPF datagrid to be the automatic Add New Row line

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I have a simple class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
class Revision {

 - int Id
 - string Description

}
```

Then, I have another class which holds an observable collection of the "Revision" class described above:

```
ObservableCollection<Revision> revisionList = new ObservableCollection<Revision>();
```

In my UI, I have a Datagrid which is two-way bound to the "revisionList" above, auto-generating columns and showing a blank line so I can add new rows.

However, what I want the datagrid to do is for the blank new line row to be the first row of the grid instead of the last one and, after that, I want the next rows to be all the Revision objects inside the "revisionList", sorted by the "Id" property, descending.

To make it clearer, suppose I have 3 revisions inside the "revisionList", what I get is the default datagrid like this:

```
 ----------------------------------
|  Id  |        Description        |
 ----------------------------------
|  0   |   Revision 00             |
 ----------------------------------
|  1   |   Revision 01             |
 ----------------------------------
|  2   |   Revision 02             |
 ----------------------------------
|  < blank add new revision line > |
 ----------------------------------
```

What I want is for the datagrid to be like this:

```
 ----------------------------------
|  Id  |        Description        |
 ----------------------------------
|  < blank add new revision line > |
 ----------------------------------
|  2   |   Revision 02             |
 ----------------------------------
|  1   |   Revision 01             |
 ----------------------------------
|  0   |   Revision 00             |
 ----------------------------------
```

Is there any way I could set up the data bindings, or any events on the datagrid I could be  using so that the datagrid would behave like this automatically?

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2314458/1305169 ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your loading your observable collection but if by chance your using a for loop you can add the blank revision before load, and then use a for loop starting from the top.

```
 var blankRevision = new Revision(); 
 revisionList.add(blankRevision);

 for (int i = YourDataSource.Count; i > 0; i--) {

      revisionList.add(YourDataSource[i-1]);
 }
```

There are other ways to do this though if this isn't helpful. Also, it maybe more helpful not to have your datagrid auto generate but instead make some DataGridTextColumns and bind the id and description to the column which will allow more customization to the columns.