# DataGrid relocate add new row to the top

Tags: wpf, datagrid

In a DataGrid view, the blank row add entries is convenient but quickly get's lost when the list is large. Can you change it's default location from the bottom to the top of the DataGrid view?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in wpf datagrid how to get the blank row on top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314458/in-wpf-datagrid-how-to-get-the-blank-row-on-top)

Answer (score 5):

I've rarely used a `DataGrid` and know nothing about its ability to add rows, but coming from a WPF/MVVM point of view, you don't need that anyway. Generally in WPF/MVVM, we manipulate data rather than UI controls, so the solution is easy. First we `Bind` our collection of data (in whatever shape we chose) to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property:

```
public ObservableCollection<DataItem> SomeDataCollection { get; set; }

...

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SomeDataCollection}" ... />
```

Now, if we want to add a new item to the bottom of the `DataGrid` we can do this in the code behind/view model:

```
SomeDataCollection.Add(new DataItem());
```

Then if we want to add a new item to the start of the collection, we can just do this:

```
SomeDataCollection.Insert(0, new DataItem());
```

Of course, you'll need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your code behind/view model to make this work, but (hopefully) you'll be doing that anyway.

---

UPDATE >>>

Sorry, I misunderstood you. I found a [`NewItemPlaceholderPosition` Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.newitemplaceholderposition.aspx) on MSDN that is used by an [`ItemCollection.IEditableCollectionView.NewItemPlaceholderPosition` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491085%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Unfortunately, those linked pages don't have an code examples, so I found one in the [in wpf datagrid how to get the blank row on top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314458/in-wpf-datagrid-how-to-get-the-blank-row-on-top) post here on StackOverflow. From the answer by @woodyiii in that post:

```
var view = CollectionView.GetDefaultCollectionView(EmployeeList)
             as IEditableCollectionView;
if(view!=null)
  view.NewItemPlaceholderPosition = NewItemPlaceholderPosition.AtBeginning;
```

This does mean that you'd have to use a `CollectionView` to get this to work, but it seems like the only way... the `NewItemPlaceholderPosition` Enumeration isn't used by anything apart from the various `CollectionView` classes.

Comment: Sorry, I am not being specific enough.  In the DataGrid xaml, you can set CanUserAddRow=true. Once sense, the DataGrid UI enables blank rows so the user can easily type in new content. This blank row defaults to the bottom. I want to locate it to the top.

Comment: This was exactly what I need!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
IEditableCollectionView cv = (IEditableCollectionView)grdSchedule.Items;
cv.NewItemPlaceholderPosition = NewItemPlaceholderPosition.AtBeginning;
```

Where `grdSchedule` is the the name of your `DataGrid`

Comment: This is a copy of the last part of the previous answer.