# Send user inputted row to top of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid where I moved the blank row for user input to the top with

```
 ((IEditableCollectionView)MyGrid.Items).NewItemPlaceholderPosition =
                                       NewItemPlaceholderPosition.AtBeginning;
```

But when a user types in a new row, the row goes to the bottom (sometimes off screen) without any feedback, and the user might think that his new row just disappeared. So I would like to put it on top.

I want to do something like

```
MyGrid.Insert(0, newRow);
```

But I don't know what to override to get access to the row as it goes into the DataGrid. Right now I don't explicitly put the user inputted row into the DataGrid, this happens automatically.

Comment: Do you have an ItemsSource ?

Comment: Yes, my ItemsSource is an ObservableCollection.

Comment: Ok so insert an item in your ItemsSource , the same way you did in your Items ..

Comment: I do not have the item to insert. The user types it in the empty row on the DataGrid and it automatically goes in. I am not sure how to get a hold of their new row before it goes in.

Comment: How does it go in ? 
Is it a built in function of the DataGrid ?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56358/datagrid-input-row 

come to this room and explain the situation , and maybe i'll be able to help.

Comment: Yes it is built in. I am looking for something to override or some event I can catch to send the new row to the beginning instead of the end of the underlying collection.

Comment: See my answer to the [DataGrid relocate add new row to the top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827433/datagrid-relocate-add-new-row-to-the-top) question.

Comment: Hi Sheridan. I did find your answer in my search, but it didn't seem to solve my problem of not knowing how to catch the new row that the user enters so I can Insert it at the beginning of my ItemSource. If I had this row before it went in then it would be easy to put it at the top.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827433/datagrid-relocate-add-new-row-to-the-top

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
    public ObservableCollection<MyDataItem> DataItems 
    {
        get
        {
            List<MyDataItem> items = new List<MyDataItem>(5);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)

            {
                items.Add(new MyDataItem { abc = abc[i], qrt = qrt[i], xyz = xyz[i] });
            }

            var observable = new ObservableCollection<MyDataItem>(items);

            var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(observable) as IEditableCollectionView;
            view.NewItemPlaceholderPosition = NewItemPlaceholderPosition.AtEnd;

            return observable;
        }
    }
```

XAML :

```
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}" CanUserAddRows="True" />
```