# Can I add a new item placeholder to ListBox in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

If I have a WPF `ListBox` bound to a collection, how can I add a new item placeholder to the end?

I understand that `IEditableCollectionView.NewItemPlaceholderPosition` might provide this, but I am unclear on how to configure it through XAML.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2977611/815938) what you want?

Comment: @kennyzx -- yes, but that's not in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

> *If I have a WPF ListBox bound to a collection, how can I add a new item placeholder to the end?*

If you have a collection data bound to your `ListBox.ItemsSource` property, then to add a new item to the end, you simply add a new, empty object to that collection:

```
YourCollectionProperty.Add(new YourDataType());
```

If you have a `DataTemplate` to define what your items look like and have a property on your data type class that is displayed, you could fill that property with whatever new item text that you wanted to:

```
YourCollectionProperty.Add(new YourDataType() { YourDisplayedProperty = "New Item" } );
```